# Retrieve data from JSON Java Android

Tags: java, json

i've got a problem to retrieve information by a JSON

The Raw Json is this

> {"date":"{\"yesterday\":\"Wed 28\",\"today\":\"Thu
>   29\",\"tomorrow\":\"Fri 30\"}"

Now how i could take this Json and format in this?

```
{
    "date":{
        "yesterday":"Wed 28",
        "today":"Thu 29",
        "tomorrow":"Fri 30"
    }
}
```

And then retry the date from the key?

```
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); 
            Log.e("RAW-JSON: ","Retrieve RAW-Json is "+jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray DATESTRING = jsonObj.getJSONArray("date");
                    JSONObject d = DATESTRING.getJSONObject(0);
                    String Ieri = d.getString("yesterday");
                    Log.e("DATE-JSON", "Retrieve DATE-Json is " + yesterday);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Not a good result.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend use the library Gson to parse a JSON document, is much easier and elegant.

```
public static date  parseJSON(String jsonArray) {
    date yourDate = new date();
    try {
        yourDate = (gson.fromJson(jsonArray, date.class));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return yourDate;
}
```

Then the class date is just a class with the same elements that exists in the JSON you want to read in your case:

```
public class date {
    private String yesterday;
    private String today;
    private String tomorrow;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONArray DATESTRING = jsonObj.getJSONArray("date")` is wrong because **"date"** is not an JsonArray but an JsonObject!

Comment: Ok how can i retrieve data? Exists some java class where if i give the key they return the argument of Json?

Comment: jsonObj.getJSONObject("date").getString("today");

Comment: Value {"yesterday":"Wed 28","today":"Thu 29","tomorrow":"Fri 30"} at date of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Unterminated object at character 12 of  all of the rest of my json

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is (assuming you want today's date):

```
String todaysDate = jsonObj.getJSONObject("date").getString("today");
```

Comment: i've got this exc

org.json.JSONException: Value {"yesterday":"Wed 28","today":"Thu 29","tomorrow":"Fri 30"} at date of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: what if you get rid of the escape chars and create a new object? like there has been stated do this : jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\\\"", "\"");
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr); 

and then what I told you will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace \" with " to get clean json string and then parse the json to read data usig JSONObjct.

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\\\"", "\"");
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```